# Where am I going wrong in solving this exponential inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$(3-x)^{ 3+x }<(3-x)^{ 5x-6 }$$

Steps I took:

$$(3-x)^{ 3 }\cdot (3-x)^{ x }<(3-x)^{ -6 }\cdot (3-x)^{ 5x }$$

$$\frac { (3-x)^{ 3 }\cdot (3-x)^{ x } }{ (3-x)^{ 3 }\cdot (3-x)^{ x } } <\frac { \frac { 1 }{ (3-x)^{ 6 } } \cdot (3-x)^{ 5x } }{ (3-x)^{ 3 }\cdot (3-x)^{ x } } $$

$$1<\frac { 1 }{ (3-x)^{ 9 } } \cdot (3-x)^{ 4x }$$

$$(3-x)^{ 9 }<(3-x)^{ 4x }$$

$$4x>9$$

$$x>2.25$$

This answer seems to be wrong. I am not sure where I went wrong in the steps that I took. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is x guaranteed to be less than 3? If not, you may be dividing both sides by a negative number.

Comment: I think you have to consider two cases in the second last step

Comment: @Element118 Can you please explain further in an answer below?

Comment: Consider the cases $2<x <3$ and $x<2$ seperatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the fact that $a^x$ is decreasing  if $0<a<1$ and increasing if $a>1$.

Now consider first $2<x <3$.  In that case the inequality is satisfied iff $2<x <9/4$.  If $x>3$ there's no solution.

Comment: So, you have to solve this analytically and algebraically in order to get the complete solution?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking ...

Comment: Well, usually I can just take any inequality, manipulate it algebraically, and I have my solution set right then and there. It seems that with this one, you have to solve it analytically as well.

Comment: What does "solve it analytically" mean?

Comment: By observing what will happen to $(3-x)$ at certain values

Answer (score 1):

The first condition you have to assume is that $3-x>0$, for the expressions to be meaningful.

Now, take the natural logarithm of both sides; since the natural logarithm is an increasing function, the inequality is preserved:
$$
(3+x)\log(3-x)<(5x-6)\log(3-x)
$$
One could now be tempted to remove the $\log(3-x)$ term from both sides, but it would be wrong, because multiplying by a negative number reverses inequalities. So we have to make three cases:

### Case 1: $\log(3-x)<0$

This means $3-x<1$ (that is, $x>2$) and the inequality becomes
$$
3+x>5x-6
$$
or $4x<9$. This gives a solution set
$$
2<x<\frac{9}{4}
$$

### Case 2: $\log(3-x)=0$

There is no solution for $x=4$, because the inequality would be $0<0$, that's false.

### Case 3: $\log(3-x)>0$

This means $3-x>1$ (that is, $x<2$). The inequality becomes
$$
3+x<5x-6
$$
or $4x>9$. The two conditions are incompatible, no solution here.

### Final step

We must put together the found solution sets (just one, in this particular case) with the top condition. This provides the final solution
$$
\boxed{2<x<\frac{9}{4}}
$$

### Note

It's actually immaterial what base the logarithm is, as long as it's greater than $1$, so the logarithm is increasing. An error would be using $\log_{(3-x)}$, because it's unknown whether it's increasing or decreasing or even existing, unless one makes a division into cases as before. Using a fixed basis is easier, in my opinion.

Where did you go wrong? In not considering that $3-x$ may be positive or negative and also in not considering that the exponential function is increasing when the basis is greater than $1$, but decreasing when the basis is in the interval $(0,1)$, while it is constant for the basis $1$ (and undefined for a negative basis).

Comment: The answer I have in my booklet is $(2, 2.25)$

Comment: @Cherry_Developer I made a silly mistake, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

$$(3-x)^{ 3+x }<(3-x)^{ 5x-6 }$$
For $3>x$
$$(3+x)\log_{3-x}(3-x)<(5x-6 )\log_{3-x}(3-x)$$
$$3-x<5x-6$$
$$x>1.5$$
Thus, $$1.5<x<3$$

Comment: Hmm, is $\log_a$ increasing for every $a>0$ (but $a\ne1$, of course).